# What happens whenever we iterate a list using reverse slicing?

Tags: python, reverse

I want to traverse an array in reverse order. Whenever we use `list[::-1]` in the `for` loop condition, does it reverse the list first and then iterate from starting of the reversed list, or does it start iterating from the last to first element of the original list without reversing?

```
listA = [1,2,3,4]
for i in listA[::-1]:
   print(i)
```

Will the run time of this code be **O(n)** or **O(2n)**?

Comment: **O(n)** and **O(2n)** are the same complexity.  You seem to be asking about raw run time instead.

Comment: `O(n)` and `O(2n)` are the same thing.  An easy way to answer your question is to look at the list after the iteration and see if it's been reversed.  (It has not.)

Comment: `listA[::-1]` creates a new list containing the reversed contents of the original list; so in itself it is O(n). Iterating it is also O(n). So overall, O(n).

Comment: What run times did you get when you did the experiment in each direction?  What is confusing about the results you got?

Comment: My doubt is whether it creates a new reversed list in the background and then iterates over it or not

Comment: using `reversed(listA)` will save memory